# How to sort an Array of Points by MergeSort in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I created Point class and I have an array list of Point objects, which I want to sort by mergesort.

Comment: *Is it possible?* Yes.

Comment: Google just told me it is.

Comment: @Baldurian Please post the search term :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about 2D or 3D points, you would have to think about defining a metric such that they are orderable.

Consider the exampe points `(1,0)` and `(0,1)` in 2D space. Is `(1,0) > (0,1)` ? Or `(1,0) < (0,1)` ? It really depends on the application.

You could e.g. take just the first component as metric, then it would be `(1,0) > (0,1)`. Or you could take the distance from a specific point, e.g. the origin `(0,0)`, in which case they would be equal.

Anyways, after you have decided on that, you can look up existing implementations of sorting algorithms (you seem to be determined about MergeSort though), on the internet. [Here](http://www.java2novice.com/java-sorting-algorithms/merge-sort/) is one example.

Most interfaces to sort function in various programming languages require either a key function (e.g. "get first component" or "distance from origin"), or a custom comparison operator.